# What determines the weather?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In **Animal Crossing: New Leaf**, some days it rains and some days it is sunny. I wonder: what determines the weather in the town each day? Is it due to weather in reality or did Nintendo just install codes for a given weather each day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is randomly determined at certain points during the day: http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Weather